# How to collect which products be seen by user while scrolling and send the product to API?

Tags: javascript

Similar to async.cargo, I want to collect which products are seen by the user when scrolling down. I can send the product to API every time when there are new products seen by the user, but wondering if I can set a delay and wait for a while, then send new collection of products to API? So I don't need to call API so frequently.

Comment: I would push to a queue and have a period flush called that takes the messages in that queue (maybe every 10 seconds) and does the send/forget. The native [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) should help with that, but simple queues aren't that challenging. You might also look into the PubSub pattern and Promises.

Comment: This would be a simple queue, imagine pushing to the queue on page scroll over your products instead of the click and the dequeue sends an async request: http://jsfiddle.net/xj50spyu/1